# How can I get bar on the top of homepage?

Tags: magento-1.9

How can i get a bar on top of the homepage? like this one. "Free delivery" text on the black horizontal bar?
[image: Link]
http://monosnap.com/image/1qKfrzgi0uXyggGhQKdKxKMsxRveb5

Answer (score 0):

You can add it the same way demo store notice is added. Find `template/page/html/notices.phtml` file and add your code on the end. For example:

```
<div class="global-site-notice">
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Hello.') ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Demo store display is done from the system setting. But how can i get this icon and other styling?